# 独学プログラマーのp.130で躓いています。

Tags: python, python3

```
import csv

with open("st.csv", "w", newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
    w.writerow(["one", "two", "three"])
    w.writerow(["four", "five", "six"])
```

このファイルは「.py」で保存すればいいのか「.csv」で保存すればいいのか分かりません。
どちらで保存しても

```
import csv

with open("st.csv", "r") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for row in r:
        print(",".join(row))
```

このプログラムを実行した時にshell上には

```
one,two,three
four,five,six
```

という結果は出ず、

```
import csv

with open("st.csv", "w", newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
    w.writerow(["one", "two", "three"])
    w.writerow(["four", "five", "six"])
```

という結果がでます。
テキストエディタで開いても同様の事が起きます。
どうすればいいのでしょうか？

Comment: 皆さんのお陰で解決しました。
協力してくださった方々ありがとうございました！

Answer (score 1):

「独学プログラマー」を持っていないので的外れかもしれませんが，ふたつのスクリプトをこの順にひとつの `.py` ファイルに保存し，それを実行すれば良いと思われます。具体的には下記を保存し実行します。

```
import csv

with open("st.csv", "w", newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=",")
    w.writerow(["one", "two", "three"])
    w.writerow(["four", "five", "six"])

with open("st.csv", "r") as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
    for row in r:
        print(",".join(row))
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！
解決しました！
こんなに早く回答が来るんですね！

Comment: Delft Viewさんのお陰でプログラミングで挫折しても頑張ろうと思えました！
本当にありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1):

@Delft View さん回答のように拡張子`.py`で保存して、プログラムを`実行する`必要があります。
(例えば`p130writecsv.py`という名前で保存して`python p130writecsv.py`のように実行する)

そうすると結果として`st.csv`というcsvファイルが出来ているでしょう。

2つ目のプログラムを実行して1つ目のプログラムが表示されるのは、色々と試行錯誤している際に1つ目のプログラムを`st.csv`という名前で保存して、その後そのままにしているのが原因と思われます。

---

貴方の質問とは関係ありませんが、同じ書籍の同じ個所で別の原因でつまづいている記事が以下にあります。
[PythonでのCSVファイルの書き出し](https://teratail.com/questions/176904)

他に同じ書籍を参考にして自習？したプログラム(おそらく書籍内容そのままではない)を保存しているリポジトリ
[j-kato732/self_study_python](https://github.com/j-kato732/self_study_python)
[hama28/Python_Test](https://github.com/hama28/Python_Test)

Comment: ありがとうございます！
kunifさんの言う通りst.csvというファイルで保存してました。
プログラマーってそんなことまで分かるんですね。
凄すぎる！
ちょっと挫けそうになってましたが、頑張ります！